# Libraries not included in javaFX jar

Tags: java, maven, javafx, plugins

I have built a javaFX application using Maven.The problem is that the javaFX jar file generated from maven, doesn't contain dependencies included.

I have included the javaFx dependency this way :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.151</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I have also included the javaFx plugin :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <vendor>Vendor</vendor>
        <mainClass>org.bsh.generator.App</mainClass>
        <jarFileName>CSVGenerator</jarFileName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-jfxjar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I build the jar using goal "build-jar", the jar generated doesn't include other dependencies. Any help please?

Comment: You shouldn't need to include JavaFX as a dependency at all; it is part of the JDK in Java 8 and later.

Comment: Okey but this is not the problem

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you specifically mean by "other dependencies"? Which ones? Can you edit your post to include the entire pom file?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies scoped as `system` are not respected, this is intentional. Only `provided` and `runtime` scoped dependencies/libraries are respected by the plugin.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.

Comment: Well i found a solution using the maven assembly plugin.It includes all the dependecies inside the generated jar.